# cllocationmanger class location updates

Tags: iphone

I am doing one application.In that i am using the `CLLOcationmanager` like below.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(findlocation:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

-(void)findlocation:(id)sender
{
//NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.delegate=self;
locationManager.distanceFilter=0.3f;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog@"%@",newlocation.timestamp];
}
```

I want to update the location for every 0.3 meters.But this delegate method is not fired for that distance. And after `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(findlocation:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];` my remaining process is working.

Comment: Can you clarify what is your question here? If it is updating for every 30cm, I think you answer it yourself — there is no way to get such fine-grained location data.

Comment: My problem is,location is not updated for every 30cm.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you.  You need to adjust distance using longitude and latitude

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { { 0.0f, 0.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f } };
    region.center = newLocation.coordinate;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.15f; 
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.15f;
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Above code uses 0.15 degrees (0.15*111 Km).

OR try to use you distanceFilter".Using distanceFilter allows you to filter out that kind of extraneous motion.